# Use JS to change the source of an image element after loading the image?

Tags: javascript, image, imagesource

Is it possible to use JS (specifically with the p5 library) to change the source of an image element? I was trying to make a very low-level slideshow on my webpage and I thought I could just do something like this (the code is also in the picture below):

```
let slide;
function setup() {
    let sliders = ['cap_1.jpg', 'cap_2.jpg', 'spidermen.jpg'];
    let i = 0;
    slide = createImg(sliders[0], 'An image of Steve Rogers');
    slide.parent('container');
    slide.class('images');
    setInterval(changeImg, 2000);
    
} 

const changeImg = () => {
    slide.src = (sliders[1])
}
```

Comment: Because you're always getting index 1, the image never changes.

Comment: document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', '/path/to/image.jpg');

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Thanks, but the webpage was supposed to change the image form the one in index 0 to index 1, and it didn't do that. What else am I doing wrong? :(
Thanks for helping again, tho :)

Answer (score 1):

The "sliders" variable isn't available to the "changeImg" function because it's in the "setup" function's [scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript). Try something like

```
let slide;
function setup() {
    let sliders = ['cap_1.jpg', 'cap_2.jpg', 'spidermen.jpg'];
    // I don't know anything about the p5 library, so I'm assuming 
    // all of the code below runs (i.e. createImg() returns an HTML img element); if not, look into functions like
    // document.createElement(), because it's not always 
    // straightforward or obvious how to change certain element 
    // attributes like classes and parents
    slide = createImg(sliders[0], 'An image of Steve Rogers');
    slide.parent('container');
    slide.class('images');
    setInterval(() => changeImg(sliders[1]), 2000);
    
} 

const changeImg = (targetUrl) => {
    slide.src = targetUrl;
}
```

Comment: FYI even if the code is running it will only change image once.

Comment: yes OP, if you're looking to make an actual slideshow work you have some more work to do - hopefully, my answer helps with your understanding of the main problem, which is how your variables are scoped

Comment: @BrendanBond Thank you so much for your help and time, I hope you have a wonderful rest of your day!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues:

1. in your `changeImg()` you are only using index `1` from the array, it never advances to the next image.
2. because `changeImg()` is in different scope from `setup()`, it won't have access to variables created inside `setup()` function, so neither `sliders` nor `i` are accessible.
3. Once the slideshow started, there is no way to stop it.

```js
function setup() {
    let sliders = ['https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj', 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9pPCK70Rw0k3wethMHb1qMaIB0VjeWLy57vYgSzKbF7oJuvO2nA0Nakk-95cvibWUDcEhYkfCKvdPKT03tXZd4M5jdhIEibLO9qw-XE=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj', 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fl-GT6w3Ls6RT4vYnbkuYUyLY3lZJH8VtZ7xzxiym9YYaoVRCnZehdz6Icd0oAf6i3H9-O5cCNs6eunlxWr_Csstgsb98DdzNdLFBOlhw9NUfHdyuQjI=w76-h102-n-l50-sg-rj'];
    let i = 0;
/*
    let slide = createImg(sliders[0], 'An image of Steve Rogers');
    slide.parent('container');
    slide.class('images');
*/
    let slide = document.createElement("img");
    slide.src = sliders[0];
    slide.title = 'An image of Steve Rogers';
    slide.className = "images";
    document.body.appendChild(slide);
    const changeImg = () => {
        slide.src = sliders[++i % sliders.length];
    }
    return setInterval(changeImg, 2000);
    
} 

let interval = setup(); //clearInterval(interval) to stop the slideshow
```